# Rote action and 10/9/8-again in nWoD

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, mage-the-awakening-2e

Playing nWoD - Mage the Awakening 2nd edition to be exact.

There is rote action dice permutation that says:

> Rote Actions: When you’ve got plenty of training and the steps you need to follow are laid out in front of you, you’ve got a significant chance of success. When you make a roll, you can re-roll any dice that do not show an 8, 9, or 10. If you’re reduced to a chance die on a rote action, don’t re-roll a dramatic failure. You may only re-roll each die once

and general 10-again rule

> Every die that comes up 10 is a success. You also roll the die again,  potentially  scoring  another  success.  If  this  second  roll  comes  up  as  another  10,  count  the  success  and  roll  it  again,  on until you roll a number other than 10. This rule is called “10-Again.” Under certain circumstances, a roll might be des-ignated “9-Again” (in which case you would reroll any die that comes up 10 or 9) or even “8-Again” (reroll any success).

Is there any explanation about how those two work together?

For example:
Player rolls 3 dices with rote-action permutation and get results of '10', '8' and '6'. 10-again allows him to reroll dice that came up as '10' - and he scores another '6'. Now, how many dices he can reroll with rote action permutation? Obviously, he can't reroll the one that came up as '8', due to rote action rules, but does the first dice counts as coming up as '10' as it did initially or as '6' as it did after reroll from 10-again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have *Chronicles of Darkness 2e*, but its predecessor has this clarification under Rote Actions, and I don't believe the dice mechanics have changed. This example focuses on chance dice, but it establishes that you resolve the “again” dice first, get exactly one reroll of the failed dice up to that point, and then resolve any new “again” dice.

> ### World of Darkness (2004), page 135
>
> You get one re-roll as a whole, and add up all successes achieved to see how well your character does.
>   […]
>   If for some reason you’re reduced to a chance roll on a rote action, a dramatic failure (a “1”) on your first roll indicates that something has gone horribly wrong from the outset. No re-roll is allowed. If your first roll results in a success (a “10”), keep re-rolling for more successes based on the “10-again” rule. When you stop getting successes, you get to make another chance roll for the rote effect, and may keep re-rolling that die if 10’s turn up.

Comment: I haven’t been able to find any thing in the 2e rules that override this.